# Laravel 5.4, vuejs and lodash error with filter function

Tags: laravel, lodash, vuejs2

I have been trying to filter out some objects by a key value:

```
           chargesAtOffense(offense) {
                return _.filter(this.charges, { offense_level: offense });
            }
```

When I log it into the console, the return array displays everything properly:

```
Array[16]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Object5: Object6: Object7: Object8: Object9: Object10: Object11: Object12: Object13: Object14: Object15: Object__ob__: Observerlength: 16__proto__: Array
```

However after binding the array to a vue model, and outputting it it just shows an empty array.

Comment: Show how you add it to the model?

Comment: This is from my VueJS console on chrome: http://image.prntscr.com/image/faf6791a9f91499c9df428d1834b9a09.png, as you can see DATA exists. But when I output it or use a v-for loop, an empty array shows up. Nothing. `<div v-for="(charges, offenseIdx) in cCharges">
            {{charges}}
        </div>`